# oracle connection string not working

Tags: sql, .net, oracle11g

On a different oracle 11g server, this variant of connection string format works:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID))); User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

but when I use this on another oracle 11g server with similar configuration, it doesn't work anymore.

When I use tnsping , the result comes out similar to the connection string above except the service name is blank.

```
Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip address)(PORT=port)))
OK (20 msec)
```

The DB is also reachable using the SQL Developer. What's wrong with my connection string? I'm working with a web service made in .NET that needs to connect to the oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out on this part SERVER = DEDICATED

> datasource =(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXX)(PORT = abc))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = my_orcl_db)